# Tetrix Prizm and ROBOTC

Tags: arduino, motor, robotc

I am currently trying to find if its possible to program a Tetrix Prizm motor controller with ROBOTC? Because I have an EV3 brain connected with the Prizm to a robot assembly with two motors, and I was searching and [here](https://www.marketwatch.com/press-release/prizmtm-brings-coding-to-the-tetrix-robotics-world-2016-10-10) it says it can use Arduino.

Comment: @jsotola That is my question can robotc program a prizm tetrix? If any difficulties let me know.

Comment: it is unclear why you are asking ..... if you have the hardware, then why don't you try to do what you are asking about?

Comment: a web search indicates that ROBOTC can be used with arduino, so the answer is `yes it is possible`